# Which are the “Must Follow” rules of PMD?

Tags: java, static-analysis, rules, pmd, white-box

I´m starting to use PMD and I really want to know which are the most important rules or the rules that anybody can´t miss when using this tool.

I´m looking for some article or page with a list of rules that must be used in PMD, this tool has a lot of rules and it's difficult to select only a few of them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question is both general and subjective.  However, the sourceforge pmd site has a list of some pre-packaged rulesets:

http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.5/rules/index.html

You should probably use at least the basic ruleset.  Beyond that, it's up to what kind of project you are working on and which rules apply to it.